# Test if table IsTemporal in EF Core 6.0

Tags: ef-core-6.0

EF Core 6.0 now supports IsTemporal() which allows you to use an MS-SQL history table. I use DbContext.OnBeforeSaving() to validate certain fields before I commit the data. If the table is temporal then I would like to save the UserId of the person who updated this line.

How do I test if the table is temporal? (i.e. by psudo-code below)

```
foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<MyBaseEntityType>())
{
   // if (entry is Temporal)
   //    set entry.Entity.UserID from IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EF Core 6.0 now supports IsTemporal() which allows you to use an MS-SQL history table

I guess you have in mind `IsTemporal()` fluent configuration API like

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().ToTable(tableBuilder =>
    tableBuilder.IsTemporal());
```

For entities configured that way, there is corresponding `IsTemporal()` metadata extension method, e.g. (requires reference to  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` assembly)

```cs
foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<MyBaseEntityType>())
{
    if (entry.Metadata.IsTemporal())
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```